# what will be the output of this program?

Tags: c

I came across this code , but when I execute it,every time it gives different answer.I tried different compiler gcc and online but both of them give different answer.here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

 void main()
{
float s;
s=4/3.3*5-2.2;
printf("%d",s);
}
```

Comment: Compile it and find out what *Undefined Behavior* is... (pay attention to the compiler warnings -- they just might save you) Hint: *passing a `float` to a `%d` (integer) format specifier invokes Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: Do you know what the problem with the code is, and you're trying to understand the misbehavior?  Or you want to know how to fix it?

Comment: `f` is float so you need to use `%f` rather than `%d` in the `printf`.

Comment: @BenVoigt acutally  it's a competitive exam question.I'm trying to understand misbehavior.

Comment: Find a more competently organised competition.

Comment: Is "Undefined Behavior" one of the answers? If not, follow @n.m.'s suggestion and find a better competition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your code, which a compiler warning would have told you, is that a float is not an integer. The "%d" format prints an integer.

On x86 or x86_64 architectures you get a random appearing value because the float value `s` is put into a register or stack location for `double` floating point values. These are not the same as integer registers. So when `printf` goes to get an integer value for `"%d"` it gets whatever happened to be left lying around.

But you could get different results on different CPU types. That's undefined behavior for you.

Comment: The second paragraph needs to be introduced by "In practice" or similar, because this certainly is not guaranteed.

Comment: @BenVoigt I suppose there could be architectures that have dual use 64 bit integer / float registers or a pure stack calling ABI.

Comment: x86 "stdcall" and "cdecl" calling conventions are among those which pass all parameters on stack, SSE on x86 and x86_64 has dual-use floating/integer registers.   But I was thinking more about archs like Itanium where reading an uninitialized value can cause a fault, or architectures where the mismatch in size might cause a page fault.  It would even be theoretically possible to have a platform where integer values are always passed by reference (so the register should contain a memory address) and by storing a float instead, the bits of the float representation form an illegal address.